# Qlik Sense webserver 404 error after installing WTServer NGINX

Tags: nginx, qliksense

I have some typical problem but perhaps it's a situation that occurs with every web server.

I have a server where Qlik Sense server runs on. In a working situation we can open the browser and can navigate to `http://localhost/qmc` or `http://localhost/hub`. A working hub of management console opens and we can do what needs to be done.

Today i tried to install another webserver NGINX and found a package WTServer where NGINX is included together with MariaDB.

I tought that after installing the WTServer it would give me an error that port 80 and port 443 is already in use so i could use other ports for NGINX, but instead it sort of 'kicked out' Qlik Sense web server.

I removed WTServer, because the Qlik Sense server is very important but now Qlik Sense gives me the error

```
Error 404 - Not found

Cannot establish a connection to Qlik Sense: Qlik Sense Management Console
```

or

```
Error 404 - Not found

Cannot establish a connection to Qlik Sense: Qlik Sense Hub
```

I know it's not that much information if you don't know Qlik Sense but i think it had something to do with settings that are still applied on my server from the WTServer installation that prevent my Qlik Sense (web) server to work.

Are there settings that i can check or change (proxy settings, TCP/IP, ...) that could fix my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WTServer](http://wtserver.wtriple.com/) Installer optimizes TCP/IP. One of the things it dose, frees ipv4 addresses in order to be used by nginx and restricts all other windows web servers to use only ipv6 addresses. This is required so that Nginx could coexist with other windows services.

To revert back, run in an elevated command prompt:

```
netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=::
```

Comment: To bad i already reinstalled the server. But because i want to know if this could been my fix i will install a new instance and i will try to have the same issue again (in test). If it does i will try your fix and let you know if this solved the problem. Before that i thank you for this answer.

Comment: You`re welcome! The latest WTServer uninstaller was updated already and runs the command above. So you might not experience the same issue

Comment: I tried to have the same issue again with a new server. So i installed Qlik Sense and WTServer and there was that problem again! After removing WTServer from that system and running above command i was able to use my Qlik Sense app again! This is something to remember in the future.